# How Can I use sigma aspherical 28-200mm on my nikon D7200

Tags: lens-mount

How Can I use sigma aspherical 28-200mm macro SLR lens on my nikon D7200.? Which adapter should I looking for this adjustment ?

Comment: Sigma lenses exist with a variety of mounts, so what is the mount on this lens? If it is the Nikon mount, you don't need an adapter.

Comment: Don't invest too much work into that project - if it is the lens I think it is, it is quirky and  not very satisfying on a 24MP DX sensor.... IIRC last time I tried one, 200mm was ok-ish, 28mm was dis ... appointing.

Answer (score 3):

Sigma is primarily known as a third-party lens manufacturer—they make lenses for several different camera mounts. For instance, the Sigma 28–200mm ƒ/3.5–5.6 Aspherical IF Macro that you're asking about was available in at least the following mounts: Canon EF, Nikon F, Pentax K, Sony / Minolta A, Sigma.

You can only mount the Nikon-mount version of the Sigma lens on your Nikon D7200. Lenses made for other lens mounts are not able to be adapted to Nikon-mount camera bodies. If your lens is not made for Nikon mount cameras, you can't mount it.

Please see, [Can I use lens brand X on interchangeable lens camera brand Y?](https://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/62000/can-i-use-lens-brand-x-on-interchangeable-lens-camera-brand-y/62003#62003)